# D3.js use d3.create element can't show in svg tag

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I follow Official documents, I want to use `d3.create()` create a `rect` and append to `svg` tag, I use chrome dev tools can see that dom structure, but I just can' see, I thought it's wired, Did I missed any part?

```
const svg = d3.select('svg').attr('width', 100).attr('height', 100)

const romanticCircle = d3.create('rect');

romanticCircle
    .attr('width', 50)
    .attr('height', 50)
    .attr('fill', 'red');

svg.append(() => romanticCircle.node())
```

Codepen Link is here.
https://codepen.io/unnhao/pen/wvGYPpV

Answer (score 2):

Per the [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/v2.0.0/README.md#create) you need to write it as d3.create("svg:rect"), otherwise you end up with a rect element in the html namespace and that won't render.

```js
const svg = d3.select('svg').attr('width', 100).attr('height', 100)

const romanticCircle = d3.create('svg:rect');

romanticCircle
    .attr('width', 50)
    .attr('height', 50)
    .attr('fill', 'red');

svg.append(() => romanticCircle.node())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg/>
```

Comment: Nice!! I think I need to watch the document more carefully.